# Elasticsearch 7.14 constant_score with two filters?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I'm having trouble creating a constant_score query in ES 7.14 with two filters. My query is:

```
"query": {
            "constant_score": {
                "filters": [
                    {"exists": {"field": "_geopoint"}},
                    {"term": {"project_id": "123"}},
                ]
            }
        },
```

Basically, I need the score where documents have any value in _geopoint for the project_id = '123'. But I get the error:

> unexpected token [START_ARRAY]

My mappings are:

```
"mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "project_id": {"type": "keyword"},
                "form_id": {"type": "keyword"},
                "submission_id": {"type": "keyword"},
                "_submitted_date": {"type": "date"},
                "_xform_id_string": {"type": "keyword"},
                "_submitted_by": {"type": "keyword"},
                "_user_id": {"type": "keyword"},
                "_project_code": {"type": "keyword"},
                "_geopoint": {"type": "text"},
                "_geolocation": {"type": "geo_point"},
            }
        },
```

I also tried with an and:

```
"filter": {
           "and": {
               "filters": [
                  {"exists": {
                     "field": "_geopoint"
                  }},
                  {"term": {
                     "project_id": "123"
                  }}
               ]
           }
       }
```

But I get a problem with the "and"

Any idea is appreciated. The official documentation on constant_score only has one filter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "constant_score": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": [
            {"exists": {"field": "_geopoint"}},
            {"term": {"project_id": "123"}},
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Now I get "[constant_score] query does not support [bool]"

Comment: My bad, try again, please

Comment: Great answer! I was struggling for more than an hour. This works like charm!

Comment: @Val this works like charm. tysm